# SQL -Extracting specific number pattern in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

The use case looks pretty much like this :

```
Column1

Test1234
12Test5678
Test6789sample
```

The objective is to extract the 4 Digit numbers (sure about the length) present within the string and store it in a separate column. The situation becomes much trickier with case 2 where the string has numbers in which we are not interested.

Comment: Tag has been added

Comment: What if there are 2 4digit numbers in the column?

Comment: That is not expected to happen in the scenario

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can take a two-step approach using `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.  First, we can strip all groups of digits occurring *five* or more times.  Then we can find a remaining digit group of 4 using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'Test6789sample1234567' AS col
)

SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[0-9]{5,}', ''), '[0-9]{4}')
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs: `6789`

### Demo

Comment: But for 2nd input will it return 5678 or 1256? Pls advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET col2=REGEXP_REPLACE(col1,'^(.*[^\\d])?(\\d{4})?([^\\d].*)?$','\\2');
```

Comment: This would fail for `1234abcd`, because your pattern asserts that something always comes before the 4 digits to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would simply use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1, '[0-9]{4}')
```

This is much trickier in earlier versions.  You might need a `case`:

```
select (case when column1 regexp '^[0-9]{4}' then substr(column1, 1, 4)
             when column1 regexp '^[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{4}' then substr(column1, 2, 4)
             when column1 regexp '^[^0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}' then substr(column1, 3, 4)
             . . .   -- repeat as many times as needed             
        end)
```